# Faster way of Selecting a row from 3 tables using same id#

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the last ID# from the table called address_contact and the code I use is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM address_contact ORDER BY lastUpdate DESC LIMIT 1") 
or die(mysql_error());  
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
$id = .$row['id'];
```

Now I would like to close that connection and open a new one and then get all of the data from the following 3 tables using that ID# that we just got:

```
Table 1: address_address
Table 2: address_contact
Table 3: address_email
```

so it would look something like this ???

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT address_contact.id,address_contact.lastname,address_contact.firstname,address_contact.primaryAddType,address_address.id,address_address.phone1,address_address.phone2,address_address.line2,address_email.id,address_email.email
FROM address_address
LEFT JOIN address_contact ON address_address.id=address_contact.id 
LEFT JOIN address_email ON address_address.id=address_email.id                  
WHERE address_contact.id = ".$id)
```

But there has to be a easier/faster way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried using a [subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824780/basic-sql-sub-query)?

Comment: First thing: use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` in new applications, it will be deprecated. Second point: have a look at SQL injection, check `$id` before inserting it (at least place single quotes around it `'".$id."'`).

Comment: if your query is working and its not slow then there is no reason for you to look into something else. The query looks good to me.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I don't agree with that. Always try to optimize your code ;-)

Comment: @Blazemonger I did but I got so lost in it that it made my head spin :( My try's are so bad that I didn't even include it in the question.

Comment: @msvuze You say you want the last id, but you're ordering by lastUpdate instead of id. Which is it you want? :)

Comment: You need to be more aware of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). `mysql_query` is a deprecated interface, it's being removed from PHP, so you should switch to something current like [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I want to get the ID# of the row that was last updated, I have a field called 'lastUpdate' that saves date/time the format is like this: YEAR-MM-DD-HH-mm-ss and I want to order by lastUpdate so that I get the ID# based on that field then I want to take that ID# and get the data from the 3 tables

Comment: @Pieter Thank you so much for your comment, I'm getting the ID# from within the database that was generated by the database so I think I'm safe from a SQL injection ???

Comment: @msvuze OK. It should be 'in your system' to add this, also data from a database can cause problems.

Comment: @msvuze Then I'd check that lastupdated has an index and test Geoffrey's and VitalityG's answers for performance, they've pretty much covered the two obvious options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a single SQL statement using a sub query to find the ID.

```
SELECT
  address_contact.id,
  address_contact.lastname,
  address_contact.firstname,
  address_contact.primaryAddType,
  address_address.id,
  address_address.phone1,
  address_address.phone2,
  address_address.line2,
  address_email.id,
  address_email.email
FROM
  address_address
  LEFT JOIN address_contact ON address_address.id = address_contact.id 
  LEFT JOIN address_email   ON address_address.id = address_email.id                  
  WHERE address_contact.id = (
    SELECT id FROM address_contact ORDER BY lastUpdate DESC LIMIT 1
  )
```

Comment: That'd afaict change the meaning of the query from the last updated to the last inserted. The description isn't very clear though, may be what the asker wants.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Fixed the answer, thanks for the pointer

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but afaik no MySQL version will allow limit in a subquery :)

Comment: That is not a good answer, if someone inserts another row between your insert and your select, then you will get the wrong row!

Comment: @mavroprovato As long as the select is for display purposes and not combined with an insert (nothing says it is), I can't see a problem. If the user sees a row that's 1ms out of date, I don't think he/she will notice :)

Comment: @mavroprovato: Where did the OP say there was an insert?, please re-read the question.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Just tested a limit in a sub query on MySQL 5.5.31, works fine.

Comment: @Geoffrey My bad, it's only restricted on an `IN` subquery, not an `=` one.

Comment: Sub query is redundant. There can be performance issues when using sub query because it is harder for query planner to optimize such queries.

Comment: @VitaliyG - 1) How is it redundant? and 2) Explain then why it can be enormously faster then a join in many circumstances?

Answer (score 2):

If this ID is for a brand new record you'd just inserted, you should be using the `msyql_last_insert_id()` function, which guarantees that you get the last insert THIS particular script/database handle did. Your method is subject to race conditiosn - if some OTHER script does an insert behind this script's back, you'll get that script's ID, not yours.

That being said, you would be better off doing

SELECT max(id) FROM yourtable

instead of the order by/limit version. It's more efficient to it this way.

The basic code sequence would be:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable ....
SELECT @id := last_insert_id();
SELECT ... FROM yourtable WHERE id = @id;
```

Comment: Sometimes the record was just edited so it's not always a new record, so that's why I use the (date/time) 'lastUpdate' field and limit 1 to get the last one ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use single query

```
SELECT address_contact.id,address_contact.lastname,address_contact.firstname,address_contact.primaryAddType,address_address.id,address_address.phone1,address_address.phone2,address_address.line2,address_email.id,address_email.email
FROM address_address
LEFT JOIN address_contact ON address_address.id=address_contact.id 
LEFT JOIN address_email ON address_address.id=address_email.id                  
ORDER BY address_contact.lastUpdate DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This will be slow as you will be sorting the data of all the joined tables also, the sub-query will be enormously faster.

Comment: @Geoffrey I would suspect that even MySQLs limited optimiser rewrites the limit to a join of a single row, I'd benchmark though to be sure.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Interested to see the results as often changing a query such as this in my experience has improved performance by orders of a magnitude, especially in older MySQL versions.

Comment: @Geoffrey Yeah, I'm making absolutely _no_ excuses for MySQL's optimizer, but it's worth running the query to check :)